# It doesn't work (html and javascript and Iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, django, iframe

Related.. (HTML, JAVASCRIPT, Iframe)

I add code into Iframe's element using javascript(Dynamically.).

After I set all of things. JavaScript in Iframe doesn't work( onclick=functionName(defined inside iframe)... doesn't identify javascript function)

what's wrong...

this is my snippet.

```
  //initialize
  var destiframe = $('#tmpresult').contents();
  destiframe.find('head').empty();
  destiframe.find('body').empty();

  //add script and style
  destiframe.find('head').append("<style></style>");
  destiframe.find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript"></script>');

  //attach customized code
      jQuery.each( code, function( i, code ) {
        switch(i){
          case 0:
                destiframe.find('style').append(code.value);

          break;
          case 1:
                destiframe.find('body').append(code.value);

          break;
          case 2:
                destiframe.find('script').append(code.value);

          break;
          default:
                console.log("empty set");
          break;
```

[image: result.]

[image: result2. with console.log]

Comment: Is the script tag even there? jQuery append() used to strip out script tags. Also probably better to create a whole script element with the code inside it before inserting in dom

Comment: thnk, I aplly that right now.

Comment: If your issue has been resolved then either restructure it in case you feel it'd be of any help for other fellow developers or else delete it.

Comment: @charlietfl it doesn't work... even my snippet could insert <script>...</script>

Comment: did you put the code in the `<script>` before inserting in dom?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. I add javascript code after inserting... I seems good but, could not call function...

Comment: Try putting an alert() or console.log inside the script tag

Comment: @charlietfl I do that, but it also could not call function. and I add another picture...(I'm Korean. therefore there are warning with Korean... I translate... 1) there are potential error cause permit to allow accessing script same location, 2) (red) 'date' is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just my mistake.

-- If someone want to refer javascript function in iframe. iframe must refer source code which define function that component in body refer...

this is my solution..

1. In 'view.py', define index s

   ```
   def upload_file(request):
       context = {'source_list':source_list,'menu_list':menu_list, 'form':fileform, 'index':1}
       return render(request, 'encyclopedia/maintab.html', context)
   ```
2. In '(template document name).html', define what to do according to index.

   ```
   {% if index == 0 %}
       <a id="nav-{{service.menu}}-tab" class="nav-item nav-link active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="{{service.menu}}-tab" href="#{{service.menu}}-tab">
             목록 보기(<- this is korean. In English "show list...")
       </a>
   {% elif index == 1 %}
       <a id="nav-{{service.menu}}-tab" class="nav-item nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="{{service.menu}}-tab" href="#{{service.menu}}-tab">
             목록 보기(<- this is korean. In English "show list...")
       </a>
   {% endif %}
   ```
3. Don't forgot to define iframe like below

   ```
   <form class="form-horizontal" method ="POST" action="./upload" >
       ...
       <input type="submit" id="transferbutton" value="vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"/>
   </form>
   ```
4. In 'Urls.py'

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^encylopedia/index$', views.index, name='index'),
       url(r'^upload$', views.upload_file, name='upload_file'),
       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   ]
   ```

It is difficult to understand Django framework... 
thnks.

but it makes some blink... when click button.