# How to process Iframe javascript functioncall

Tags: javascript, html, django

I found out javascript function call in iframe is transmitted to view.py or url.py ... therefore if function is not defined in parent page.. it shows "function is undefined...."

How can I process javascript function call in its own javascript function.

the result of explorer is "date function is undefined..."

Thnks in advance.

ref.

```
  destiframe.find('head').append("<style></style>");
  destiframe.find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript"></script>');

  //attach customized code
      jQuery.each( code, function( i, code ) {
        switch(i){
          ...
          case 2:
                destiframe.find('script').append(code.value);
```

and.
Assuming that below is customized html code.

```
  <html>
    <head>
     <style>
     </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function date(){
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date();
    }
    </script>
    <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

    <button onclick="date()" type="button">
    Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Result is 
Undefined function date().

Comment: Please post code on a [mcve] instead of pictures of code

Comment: @mplungjan ok I fix it.

Comment: If this is in a webpage inside script tags then you will kill all scripts. `destiframe.find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript"></script>');`  -you need to escape the `<\/script>`

Comment: @mplungjan I already do that... :( Is there any function to receive request from iframe in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that premise("javascript function call in iframe is transmitted to view.py or url.py..") is not correct. javascript function call in iframe is transmitted to source code which document is referring. therefore iframe should refer src code.

It is implemented by defining src attibute in iframe. if you want to know how to implement see below QnA

[It doesn't work (html and javascript and Iframe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362818/it-doesnt-work-html-and-javascript-and-iframe)